# When flying to Canada via London, where do I pass customs and immigration?

Tags: transit, customs-and-immigration, airports, london

Where will I go through Immigration/ Customs if I fly from Sweden to London (connection) to Canada?

Answer (score 4):

You will pass through customs and immigration when you first land in Canada.

There is also passport exit control when you leave Sweden.

In London there is no customs and no immigration for international-to-international transit passengers, although you will go through a security screening.

Comment: Note that the OP would need to go through immigration+customs if they weren't able to through-check bags, or if they had an overnight, or if they were a smoker!